# Has CERN recently found evidence for a Z-prime boson?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs

In the recent [Higgs seminar](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/record/1406042) at 73:38 [Guido Tonelli](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/record/1173837)  the spokesman for CMS, makes a mistake and refers to a Z-prime in a context that would imply that they see them frequently. He swiftly backpedals amid the general hilarity of the concept. However a few seconds later he remarks that "There is something behind this", implying that there is a reason why he might have Z-primes on his mind and he says "Fabio knows" referring to Fabiola Gianotti who leads the ATLAS team.

Can we expect some announcement regarding a Z-prime boson? Does anyone have more information?

Comment: Haha, you're trying to read a lot, indeed. Let me just guess that "Fabio knows" almost certainly doesn't mean "Fabiola knows". The former is male, the latter is female. It could be Fabio Maltoni see e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0505014 or someone else.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds curt, but the answer is "Not yet." (and this was written at the end of 2015.)

Comment: I think this is a dated question. He was probably referring to what ended up identified as the Higgs in 2012 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson#Discovery_of_candidate_boson_at_CERN

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as outdated.